# Foreign Language Not Appearing Correctly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am currently working on a Phonegap Project. It is a tourism app. I am trying to display some korean characters. The Content is saved in a database inside `index.js` and it is called in my `p_attractiondetails.html`. However, the korean characters are not displayed correctly. I have tried adding the lang attribute, `lang = "ko"` and the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` but still no luck on displaying the characters correctly. Can someone please help me? Here is my code.

`index.js`

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ATTRACTIONS');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ATTRACTIONS (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, data TEXT)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ATTRACTIONS (id, title, data) VALUES ("1", "La Mesa Dam", "The La Mesa Dam is a dam in Quezon City in the Philippines. It is part of the Angat-Ipo-La Mesa water system, which supplies most of the water supply of Metro Manila. The La Mesa Dam is an earth dam whose reservoir can hold up to 50.5 million cubic meters occupying an area of 27 square kilometers. <br><br> Metro Manila and its surrounding areas are divided into two water concessionaires: Maynilad Water (red) and Manila Water (blue). <br><br> The water collected in the reservoir is treated on-site by the Maynilad Water Services, and at the Balara Treatment Plant further south by the Manila Water. Both water companies are private concessionaires awarded by the Metropolitan Waterworks and Sewerage System, the government agency in charge of water supply.")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ATTRACTIONS (id, title, data) VALUES ("2", "La Mesa Ecopark", "La Mesa Ecopark Data")');
}
// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ATTRACTIONS', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var title;
    var data;
    var i;
   //alert("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        title = results.rows.item(0).title;
        data = results.rows.item(0).data;
        //alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Title = " + results.rows.item(i).title + " \nData =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
    }

    $(function (){
        $('.title').html(title);
        $('.data').html(data);
    })
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    //alert("success!");
}

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

}
```

`p_attractionsdetails.html`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ko">
  <head>
     <title>QC App</title>
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr" />
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/photoswipe.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/listview-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="LaMesaDam" data-title="LaMesaDam">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Attractions</h1>
            <a href="#left-panel2" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></a>
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="desc_img my-page ui-content jqm-fullwidth">
            <div>
                <img class="imgdisplay" src="images/LaMesaDam.png">
                <p> <img style="width:16px;" src="images/icons/193-location-arrow.png"> 12 km </p>
            </div>
            <div lang="ko" role="main" class="my-page desc_page ui-content jqm-fullwidth">
                <h1 lang="ko" class="title"></h1>
                <h5 lang="ko" class="data"></h5>
                <a href="#nearby" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Nearby Places</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- id nav-panel-->
        <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel2" data-theme="b">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="false">
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="index.html" rel="external">Home</a></li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">Categories</li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Attractions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Dining</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Holy Places</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Hospitals</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Shopping</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#attractions">Transport</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div>

    </body>
```

I am new to Web Technologies. Thank you so much.

Comment: is the html file saved in utf-8 encoding?

Comment: i tried utf-8. still problem in displaying characters. in my code above i used `euc-kr` since it is for korean according to some online resources. still no luck.